# Firebase TLS Restrictions

Tags: firebase, ssl, firebase-realtime-database, tls1.2

I am working with a financial technology company called Dwolla who provides an API for attaching banking information to a user and charging / sending ACH payments.

They need me to upgrade my TLS minimum to 1.2 (disabling TLS 1.0, the GCP default) for the url of my firebase database.

I have not been able to find any documentation on this online at all.

Does anyone know how to do this in GCP or Firebase?

Some people have told me that I have to create a load balancing layer to connect an SSL policy to after creating backend services in GCP.

Is all of this necessary? Thank so much!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see *.firebaseio.com already has TLS 1.2 enabled.

I quickly tested this on https://www.cdn77.com/tls-test, and entered yourproject.firebaseio.com/doesntmatter.json as the URL.

[image]

Comment: Hey Frank! Yes, this is true. I need to disable 1.0 and 1.1 making TLS 1.2 my minimum. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Ah. There's nothing you can do to control that unfortunately. You could [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) to see if they can configure it per project, but I'm not sure they can as the certificates apply for the entire server/infrastructure.

Comment: For people wondering about TLS 1.3 being enabled for Firebase Functions, I can confirm that it is enabled (checked in Sept 2020).

Comment: @MikePerhats were you able to find a solution for this?

Comment: @Haplo unfortunately not. I would talk to a rep at Dwolla.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Hosting now has TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.0 disabled, as expected.

Comment: I still TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 as available in my firebase https functions

Comment: @MikeT Good to know, I was talking about Firebase Hosting, I edited my answer.